# What does <DATA> mean in Perl error messages?

Tags: perl, error-handling

[image]

I'm trying to debug a error I am currently experiencing in Perl, and my first clues are the files and the lines stated. However, I'm not sure what <**DATA**> is.

So what is it?

Answer (score 4):

It means you had read 228 lines from the `DATA` file handle when the error occurred. It's unlikely to be relevant in this case.

It's even less likely to be relevant when the handle in question is `DATA`. `DATA` allows a program to read data from the end of its source file. It's usually used to store hard-coded data or part of the program itself. It's usually read from start to finish early in the program execution. But few bother to close the handle, so unrelated error message end up tagged with the number of the last line of that data.

Comment: In fact, except in trivial scripts, it's NEVER relevant.  It really _should_ be using a per-module counter and not a meaningless global one, but the perl devs are loath to break the overall format of errors beyond the text portions of the error message itself.  Basically the message is a  legacy appendage from perl4 that can be ignored now.

Comment: @Chuck Adams, So not true! It is sometimes meaningful, and it can save you a lot of time when it is.

Answer (score 1):

`<DATA>` is default filehandle for `__DATA__` or `__END__` tokens in Perl. 

 
What it means is, there should be a `__DATA__` or `__END__` sections towards the end of the perl script you are running. Whatever text you have after those tokens is considered by perl interpreter as a file and is made available to the program through the `<DATA>` file handle.

```
print while (<DATA>); 
# End of Perl script. Whatever follows goes into <DATA> fh. 

__DATA__
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
```